# When can I use a transformation to make an derivation problem easier (example in body)?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

The example, from my homework, is to find the critical points of $f(x,y)=(x^2 + y^2)e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$. I can bash it out, but I want to be confident I'm seeing the most creative way to solve it. This just begs to be restated somehow in polar form. WolframAlpha even tells me that the critical points lie at the origin and on the unit circle.

If I make the substitution, the problem becomes incredibly simple. In polar form 
- $f(r, \theta) = r^2e^{-r^2}$ - it doesn't even depend on $\theta$, so the problem is just simple single-variable calculus. Is this a valid argument? Why or why not? How does it hold up in general?

Answer (score 1):

Note that in polar form,

$$f(r) = r^2e^{-r^2}$$

and set,

$$\frac{df}{dr} = e^{-r^2}\cdot 2r(1-r^2) = 0$$

which yields $r=0$, hence the origin.

Comment: You're right, I made a simple math error. I edited my question in response. However, you haven't answered the heart of my question, which was "are we allowed to make these substitutions in general, and how do we justify them?"

Comment: @RobinAldabanx - The Cartesian and polar coordinates are equivalent. They are exchangeable. Depending on the characteristic of the problem, you may use either for convenience. You should get the same answer.

Comment: It also yields $r=1$, hence the unit circle mentioned in the question.